# Metpy HRRR Cross Section

Tags: python-3.x, weather, python-xarray, metpy

I am working on creating cross sections of HRRR model output, I have read in the grib files using xarray with pynio as the engine and then converted this files to netcdf so I can work with them on my windows machine, therefore I am wondering if this is causing these issues.

Here is a what my dataset looks like after reading in the netcdf with xarray: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAc8t.png)

After reading in the data I try to follow the Metpy cross section/ Xarray tutorials by parsing the data:

```
data = ds.metpy.parse_cf()
```

Which yields this new dataset:[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9sT0.png)
It created the crs coordinate so I assumed it worked somewhat correctly.

Following this I created a contour map of 700mb RH, winds, and elevation(different data set) where I parsed the RH from the data dataset and also pulled out the x and y

```
RH = data.metpy.parse_cf('RH_P0_L100_GLC0')
x, y = RH.metpy.coordinates('x', 'y')
```

This all worked and I could produce a nice looking plot no problem. So next I wanted to make a cross section. Following the example in the documentation:

```
start = (40.3847, -120.5676)
end = (39.2692, -122.3784)
cross = cross_section(data, start, end)
```

which gave these errors:[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN6Hj.png)

So then I instead tried using the RH variable from above since

```
RH.metpy.x
```

gave the x-dimension. But running

```
cross = cross_section(RH, start, end)
```

gave this error instead:[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCKqc.png)

So I'm just wondering if I missed a step in parsing the original dataset or if the grib to netcdf conversion messed something up or if this is even possible using metpy?

In general I am just working towards creating a cross section like the one in the example: https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/cross_section.html#sphx-glr-examples-cross-section-py

As a bonus question would it be possible to fill terrain under the plots?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [MetPy's cross section interpolation](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/dev/api/generated/metpy.interpolate.cross_section.html#metpy.interpolate.cross_section) relies on the x and y dimensions being present in the Dataset/DataArray as dimension coordinates (see the description in xarray's documentation [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html#coordinates)). In your dataset, the x and y dimensions of `ygrid_0` and `xgrid_0` are listed as dimensions without coordinates, hence the problem.

However, since this situation is commonly encountered in meteorological data files, MetPy's current implementation may be too stringent. I would suggest opening an issue on [MetPy's issue tracker](https://github.com/unidata/metpy/issues).

In regards to your bonus question, so long as you have terrain level data in the same vertical coordinate as your data, you can use the [`fill_between()`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html) method in matplotlib to fill in terrain under the plots.

Answer (score 0):

I have nearly the same problem.

> ValueError: Data missing required coordinate information. Verify that your data have been parsed by MetPy with proper x and y dimension coordinates and added crs coordinate of the correct projection for each variable.

if i try this:

```
cross = cross_section(data, start, end)
```

the xarray looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:           (bnds: 2, height: 61, height_2: 1, height_3: 60, height_4: 61, height_5: 1, lat: 101, lev: 1, lev_2: 1, lev_3: 1, lon: 121, time: 24)
Coordinates:
  * height            (height) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 ... 58.0 59.0 60.0 61.0
  * height_3          (height_3) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 ... 57.0 58.0 59.0 60.0
  * lev               (lev) float64 0.0
  * lev_2             (lev_2) float64 400.0
  * lev_3             (lev_3) float64 800.0
  * lon               (lon) float64 -30.0 -29.5 -29.0 -28.5 ... 29.0 29.5 30.0
  * lat               (lat) float64 -10.0 -9.5 -9.0 -8.5 ... 38.5 39.0 39.5 40.0
    crs               object Projection: latitude_longitude
  * height_2          (height_2) float64 10.0
  * time              (time) float64 2.017e+07 2.017e+07 ... 2.017e+07 2.017e+07
  * height_4          (height_4) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 ... 58.0 59.0 60.0 61.0
  * height_5          (height_5) float64 2.0
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    height_bnds       (height, bnds) float64 ...
    height_3_bnds     (height_3, bnds) float64 ...
    lev_bnds          (lev, bnds) float64 ...
    lev_2_bnds        (lev_2, bnds) float64 ...
    lev_3_bnds        (lev_3, bnds) float64 ...
    z_ifc             (height, lat, lon) float32 ...
    topography_c      (lat, lon) float32 ...
    fis               (lat, lon) float32 ...
    con_gust          (time, height_2, lat, lon) float32 ...
    gust10            (time, height_2, lat, lon) float32 ...
    u                 (time, height_3, lat, lon) float32 ...
```

I mean there is a lat lon grid... is there a workaround to use the cross_section for a lat lon grid?
or can i rename the lat lon to x and y?

Best